# How to add sherlock library to my project

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, tortoisesvn

i downloaded project from Tortoise SVN repository, and how to add android sherlock library to my project, that sherlock library is in my workspace.

Comment: import to eclipse and reference the same in your android project

Answer (score 0):

you just import this library into your project area of eclipse. And Add this action sherlock library with your uses of project. How to Add the library with your project?
Right Click of your proejct -> Properties -> Android -> Add (click here and select your library).
[image]

In this library android support v4 library already there then there is no need to put android-support v4 library in your project. If this is availability in your project libs then remove from there.

Comment: Hi Sunil, i did like this, but it is showing red cross symbol after adding these libraries

Comment: ok try to save your project some where and again try same way and make clean and build i hope it will work

Answer (score 0):

Import it from your works space and make it as library project by

> alt+enter-->android-->tick on is library

and add it to your project by

> go to your project-->alt+enter-->add-->select your sherlock project

Thats it..

Answer (score 0):

1. Download the project from [this page](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC0QFjAA&url=http://actionbarsherlock.com/&ei=EJSdUq-5GeW70wWDzoGQBQ&usg=AFQjCNEKyOYK1H-iAiI67o4J8dIPJNL9TA&sig2=HvePfnEBG-pYApSQqJhwRw&bvm=bv.57155469,d.d2k)
2. Import the project to your workspace
3. Right click on your project -> Properties -> Android.
4. In the `Library` section, click the `Add` button, and chose the `actionbarsherlock` in the list, then OK.
5. That's all.